# How do I get the size of a multi-dimensional array in an Arduino sketch?

Tags: arduino

I have a whole bunch (~10k) of frames for my led matrix which I'm putting onto my arduino like this:

```
  static const uint8_t PROGMEM
  frames[][105] = {
      {0,0,0,0,5,14,14,9,0,0,0,0,251,0,0,
    0,0,0,3,255,255,255,255,252,42,2,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,8,86,255,255,255,255,62,62,58,37,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,1,12,31,82,252,252,39,32,2,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,250,24,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,253,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,253,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,8,58,255,255,255,251,23,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,4,27,181,255,255,255,255,247,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,251,234,226,227,194,53,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,54,28,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
```

In this case, the length of the outer array is 2. To save me updating a constant value every time I generate new frames, is there a way of calculating the length of this array?

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(frames)` returns the size of whole array in bytes.

`sizeof(frames[0])` returns the size of the first row (which is exact the same as all other rows) in bytes.

`sizeof(frames[0][0])` returns the size of the first item of the first row (which is exact the same as all other items) in bytes.

Therefore

`sizeof(frames) / sizeof(frames[0])` - number of rows

`sizeof(frames[0]) / sizeof(frames[0][0])` - number of columns (105)

You can define a macro like

`#define array_length(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))`

and use it:

`array_length(frame)` - number of rows

`array_length(frame[0])` - number of columns

Answer (score 0):

You can caluclate it directly from `frames` using `sizeof`:

```
int len = sizeof(frames) / (sizeof(uint8_t) * sizeof(frames[0]));
```